# MySQL Update doesn't work, but delete works perfect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'samagulf', 'wordpress');
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["country"]);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["city"]);
$for = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["for"]);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["title"]);
$details = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["details"]);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["price"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["email"]);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["phone"]);
$photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["photo"]);

if($input["action"] === 'edit') {

    $query = "UPDATE wp_wpdatatable_1
        SET country=' " . $country . " ',city=' " . $city . " ',for=' " . $for . " ',title=' 
        " . $title . " ',details=' " . $details . " ',price=' " . $price . " ',email=' 
        " . $email . " 
        ',phone=' " . $phone . " ',photo=' " . $photo . " '
        where wdt_ID=' " . $input["wdt_ID"] . " ' ";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

if($input["action"] === 'delete') {
    $query = "DELETE FROM wp_wpdatatable_1 
        where wdt_ID=' " . $input["wdt_ID"] . " ' ";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

echo json_encode($input);

?>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: nothing is working perfectly here. Trust me

Comment: As above, use prepared statements, one of the issues I can see will be fixed by that change. You have extra space in the column names. country=' " . $country . " ',city=' " . $city . " '. Should be country='" . $country . "',city='" . $city . "' . And then of course all the vars need to be escaped to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: The vars only need to be escaped if not using prepared statements. If prepared statements are used, it will prevent most SQL injection, and fixes any pesky quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here, use prepared statements. This will solve the issues you have such as quoting. Also, it prevents SQL injection. N.B You do not need to escape anymore.It's not necessary when using prepared statements

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE wp_wpdatatable_1 SET country=?, city=?, for=?, title=?, details=?, price=?, email=? phone=? photo=? WHERE wdt_ID=?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $country, $city, $for, $title, $details, $price, $email, $phone, $photo, $input['wdt_ID']); //bind placeholders to values

if($stmt->execute() == true){//check for success/failure(returns true/false)
    echo 'Updated';//it worked
} else {
    echo 'Failed to update: '.$connect->error; //Oops error. 
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but Unfortunately no response, no change, the same, no error message but no change,im using live table data and using jquery.tabledit plugin ,,the delete is perfect,but the problem  is with edit its return nothing doesnt show error and do nothing effect on db